# Why do I get an error when initializing an object of my defined Reference Class?

Tags: r

I'm creating a generator for a reference class object called "student", but when trying to then initialize an object of this class I get an error. I've tried initializing two different ways (both displayed below) and gotten two separate errors. The code I'm using, and the errors that result, are below. Can someone please explain where I've gone wrong?

1) Initializing directly from generator - no named arguments (This is the error I get consistently, so long as I don't provide argument names to the generator)

```
student <- 
  setRefClass("student",
              fields = 
                list(name = "character",
                     age = "numeric",
                     GPA = "numeric"))
s <- student("John", 21, 3.5)


Error in initialize(value, ...) : cannot use object of class “numeric” in new(): class “student” does not extend that class
5.
stop(gettextf("cannot use object of class %s in new(): class %s does not extend that class", dQuote(Classi), dQuote(Class)), domain = NA)
4.
initialize(value, ...)
3.
initialize(value, ...)
2.
methods::new(def, ...)
1.
student$new("John", 21, 3.5)
```

2) Initializing using "new" method explicitly and named arguments

```
student <- 
  setRefClass("student",
              fields = 
                list(name = "character",
                     age = "numeric",
                     GPA = "numeric"))
s <- student$new(name = "John", age = 21, GPA = 3.5)


Error in initialize(value, ...) : invalid names for slots of class “student”: name, age, GPA
5.
stop(sprintf(ngettext(sum(is.na(which)), "invalid name for slot of class %s: %s", "invalid names for slots of class %s: %s"), dQuote(Class), paste(snames[is.na(which)], collapse = ", ")), domain = NA)
4.
initialize(value, ...)
3.
initialize(value, ...)
2.
methods::new(def, ...)
1.
student$new(name = "John", age = 21, GPA = 3.5)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the errors you're seeing.  Your second example works fine for me; your first one throws different errors, but works with named parameters (`student(name = "John", age = 21, GPA = 3.5)`).  What version of R are you using?  And does it work with a new session?

Comment: try this s <- student(name="John", age=21, GPA=3.5)

Comment: 1. I'm in version 3.6.1

2. I've tried using the field names in the initialization already, this results in the second error for me

Comment: New session did the trick!